# Mismatch between Axes -> True and Frame ->True

Tags: plotting

Using `Axes -> True` of the following........

```
Plot[(2/Sqrt[6]) Sin[
   0.5 ArcSin[Sqrt[(3 R^2)/((2 - R)^2 + 3 R^2)]]], {R, 0.0, 1.3}, 
 PlotRange -> {0.0, .23}, Axes -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {d/a, Subscript[Sin\[Theta], 13]}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold]]
```

I am getting a plot starting from (0,0)

---

But using `Frame->True` what i am getting throuh

```
Plot[(2/Sqrt[6]) Sin[
   0.5 ArcSin[Sqrt[(3 R^2)/((2 - R)^2 + 3 R^2)]]], {R, 0.0, 1.3}, 
 PlotRange -> {0.0, .23}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {d/a, Subscript[Sin\[Theta], 13]}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold]]
```

is not starting from (0,0). Instead it is starting from (-.05,0)

---

In the second case, y-axis has been shifted from x=0. How to fix it?
P.S.- since i don't have 10 reputation , I am unable to post images.

---

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot[(2/Sqrt[6]) Sin[0.5 ArcSin[Sqrt[(3 R^2)/((2 - R)^2 + 3 R^2)]]], {R,0.0,1.3},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {0, .2}}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {d/a, Subscript[Sin[Theta], 13]},
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @HyperGroups. Problem solved, using PlotRange -> {{0, 1.3}, {0, .23}} insted of {R, 0.0, 1.3}, PlotRange -> {0.0, .23}

Comment: Just a tip: you can export your graphics by right clicking on it. No need for a screenprint like you seem to have done. Szabolcs' SE uploader is currently broken, but when it is fixed it is the best tool for posting mma images.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, actually I did that, but due to a third party link it looks like that.
Thanks for Szabolcs' SE uploader idea. I didn't know that.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries heihei, sometimes I really hate that Save as image's defult format is PDF,,,and I really love the Snipping Tool of windows V/7/8,